# Azure Service Bus - SuscriptionClient.BeginAcceptMessageSession() and TimeoutException

Tags: azure, servicebus, azureservicebus

The documentation leads one to believe that `BeginAcceptMessageSession()` will throw a `TimeoutException` if the amount of time specified in the `serverWaitTime` parameter is exceeded. This does not always seem to happen.

So, is the behavior of this thing such that it is not supposed to hand back a `MessageSession` if there are no messages in the Topic (i.e. it waits a certain period of time, and upon finding no messages, it throws the `TimeoutException`)? Or, rather, does it only time out if it cannot answer back within the time frame, regardless of whether or not there messages?

I am conducting VERY simple testing on an empty Topic, and an empty Subscription. Using a 5 second timeout value, sometimes it throws the `TimeoutException` and sometimes it does not.

What gives? Why is this thing not consistent? What is the rule for when the TimeoutException will or will not be thrown? Can I get a `MessageSession` back on an empty Subscription?

These docs are downright sparse.

Thank you for any help that you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the undocumentation is pretty impressive alright.

Are you `Close()`ing the `MessageSession` in the case where you do get it?

Remember the returned object represents a token which grants you exclusive rights to dequeue from the topic until you return it or someone else 'wins' it.